# How significant is (int) within a statement?

Tags: c++

If I have:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  float a,b,c;

  b = 7;
  c = 2;
  a = (int) (b / c);

  std::cout << a; 
}
```

Does (int) only affect the data type during cout so that 'a' can be printed as an integer or does it affect 'a' as a variable changing it to an 'int'?

Comment: _How significant is (int) within a statement?_ in this particular example, it is truncating the results of floating point division to end up with just an integer value stored into `float a`.  It throws out the remainder so for `7 / 2` you end up with `3`. If we remove the cast to `int`, then `float a` becomes `3.5`.

Comment: So if I were to use 'a' as a variable for another statement, would it be a float or an int?

Comment: The cast to `int` was just on the division operation, so `a` is still technically a `float`. The type of variable doesn't change. Look at R Sahu's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case it converts from a `float` value, the result of `b/c` into an int, then as `a` is still a `float`, converts it back to a `float`.

This is an easy, if sometimes problematic way of rounding something to an integer value.

Remember that in C++ variables never change their fundamental type. Something defined as a `float` stays a float forever. You can force other values into the same memory location, you can recast them, but the variable itself always has a fixed intrinsic type.

Answer (score 4):

> Does `(int)` only affect the data type during `cout` so that `a` can be printed as an integer or does it affect `a` as a variable changing it to an `int`?

Neither.

```
a = (int)(....);
```

only changes what is assigned to `a`. In this case it truncates the floating point number and assigns the integral part of the number to `a`.

It does not change how `a` is processed in `cout << a`.  You will notice a truncated value in the output. However, the reason for that is that a truncated value got assigned to `a` in the previous statement not because `cout << a` is processed differently.

It does not change the type of `a` to an `int`. The type of a variable cannot be changed in C++. It remains unchanged for the entire life of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Cast does not change the type of a variable the casted value is assigned to.
In your case, result of `b/c` is casted (truncated) to an `int`, which is then promoted to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `int` is a cast datatype.

What the computer are thinking

Inside the main function:

```
float a, b, c;
```

Declaring 3 variables of data_Type float.

```
b = 7;
c = 5;
```

Assigned value of 7 to b and value 5 to c.

```
a = (int) (b / c);
```

A is equal to b/c ==> 7/5 ==> 1.4, wait, the programmer asked to cast the data as int so 1.4 ==> 1

```
std::cout << a;

Output: 1.0
```

Hope this help